# How can I emit values with delay in RXJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array of values `[1,2,3]` .

I want to emit each value with  delay

I've managed to do it with the `zip` operator :

```
 Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
   .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000), x => x)
   .subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
```

**Question:**

Is there any more appropriate operator for such task ?   Involving an inner observable seems ( to me) incorrect approach.
Should I unsubscribe the inner Observable  manually ?  Becuase basically no one tells it to stop.

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/nefuvevavo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

Comment: @user184994 that's not the same as what I wanted. I want to emit 1....delay...2 .....delay.....3. Not ....delay......1,2,3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delay each emission itself and wait until the previous one completed. Like this for example:

```
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
   .concatMap(x => Observable.of(x).delay(1000)) // or Observable.timer(1000).mapTo(x)
   .subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
```

If you want to use `zip` you don't need to unsubscribe the `timer` but you need to tell it to complete (for example with `take()` or `takeUntil()`).

Comment: What inner subscription? `Observable.of(x)` emits one item and completes, you don't need to unsubscribe Observables if you know they always complete.

Comment: Martin - I didn't understand how can I make (using zip) complete the inner observable : it is like this : ? `Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
   .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).takeUntil(???), x => x)
   .subscribe((e) => console.log(e));`

Comment: `takeUntil(subject)` takes a `Subject` and when the chain completes you'll call `next` on the Subject. `.subscribe(undefined, undefined, () => subject.next());`

Comment: Nice...........BTW  - I was expecting that such FW will know that there is an inner observable which should complete if the parent is complete.